# Set value to DataGridTextBoxCell in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to safe users from error message by check if user entered more then maximum allowed size to my DataGridViewCell.

I'm making :

```
private void dataGridView3_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
    {
        string selected = (dataGridView3[e.RowIndex, 1] as DataGridViewTextBoxCell).FormattedValue.ToString();
        if (selected.Length > 50)
        {
            dataGridView3[e.RowIndex, 1].Value = selected.Take(50).ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

selected is my text but , I've got error message on updating : Can't convert string to int32...
and if I use = 0 it just makes no sense. What's wrong here ?

Error is coming when I updating texbox with Length > 50 , it says that my value is not integer. But it must be a string. I just readed a string from the same cell.

Comment: Can you please elaborate as to where to issue is, not clear from your question

Comment: error is coming after cell edit

Comment: I am not very sure if that could be the issue value takes in a **object** so should have no problem. Check if the underlying datasource expects that column value as **'int'**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misplace rows and columns in

```
dataGridView3[e.RowIndex, 1]
```

it should be column first, then row:

```
dataGridView3[1, e.RowIndex]
```

Besides, do you have to do casting on DataGridViewTextBoxCell? It works for me:

```
string selected = dataGridView3[1, e.RowIndex].FormattedValue.ToString();
```

And my sugesstion: why use it in CellEndEdit, not in CellValidating event? You could then simplify to:

```
e.FormattedValue.ToString()
```

**Edit**
Cell validating is fired more frequent than EndEdit: even on cell selection change. If it's not OK for you, then rather stay with CellEndEdit as you did. And, as mentioned, make sure datasource holds string, not integer.
By the way: in my VS there is no Take() function , I replaced it with Substring(), try like this:

```
private void dataGridView3_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
    {
        string selected = dataGridView3[1, e.RowIndex].FormattedValue.ToString();

        if (selected.Length > 50)
        {
            dataGridView1[3, e.RowIndex].Value = selected.Substring(0, 50);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you mean **columns first and then rows** and not the other way round

Comment: still got a troubles with it. 1st - CellValidating even works even if I didn't edit a cell.

Comment: 2nd , my cell value becomes "System.Linq.Enumerable+<TakeIterator>d__3a`1[System.Char]"

Comment: @ncdy are you sure the datasource is not expecting a int32 value ?

Comment: @V4Vendetta yes, I've got a text values there.

Comment: @nCdy the Linq .Take() method doesn't work how you think it does. It returns an IEnumerable. Use substring instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to Cast the String to a correct Integer value. You are trying to set a Integer value with a String, and it cannot do the conversion.

Comment: Where do you think is the error you offering a solution for ?

Comment: No , I'm trying to set a text for DataGridViewTextBoxCell